# Set css property using javascript-jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update css property dynamically,

Actuall css property:

```
#Controls > ul > li:hover:after{
top:100px;
/* other property */
}
```

I need to set top = -100px dynamic.

**What I did :**

```
$("#Controls > ul > li:hover:after").css("top", "-100%"); // Its not working
```

**2nd Option what I tried :**

Created a new css class :

```
 .topTip{top:-100%  !important;}
```

then

```
 $("#Controls > ul > li:hover:after").addClass("topTip") //Again not working.
```

Please suggest if you have other options.

Thanks for viewing question.

**More EXPLANATION**

This is used for tooltip UI, When hover mouse over li tag.

Currently (default) tooltip visible on bottom of text "success subscribe"

**HTML : **

```
<div id="Controls">
     <ul class="hideMobile">
            <li tooltip="This is tooltip" class="SubscribeTool">
              <a id="#" class="liked" > success subscribe</a>
           </li>
```

**Complete css:**

```
 #Controls > ul > li:hover:after {
 position:absolute; top:100%; left:-5px; padding:0 10px; margin-top:5px; content:attr(tooltip); width:auto; height:auto; 
 display:inline-block;
 background:#e55302; color:#fff; font:600 11px/25px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; 
 z-index:9999999999 !important; border-radius:2px; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
```

}

Now, after some functions, I need to display tooltip with top=-100%

Comment: If that code runs before the affected elements are part of the DOM, it will have no effect.

Comment: above jQuery code is going to run after evrything - DOM loaded completely .

Comment: Am I getting u right, that you want to change the li:after?

Comment: can u provide the jsfiddle or give sample html code?

Comment: My guess is that the element is not loaded before the script. Move script into an $(document).ready(); If that does not fix it, can you please tell us what your selector returns when run from console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying to do, because pseudo elements are not part of the DOM tree, so you can't change their properties with DOM API.

Instead you can try another approach: add one more class that would define necessary styles. For example:

```css
#Controls > ul > li.topTip:hover:after {
    top: -100px;
}
```

<sub>*Note: `!important` in not needed in this case*</sub>

and then assign new class

```
$("#Controls > ul > li").addClass("topTip");
```

Comment: You are the GURU..!!  Its an awesome ans. and explanation. You deserve for 39.9k

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't target pseudo-elements (`:after`) with JavaScript. They are CSS-specific and not exposed to the DOM for JavaScript to access (or modify).

If `-100px` is a fixed value, a workaround to this is to add a separate class to your CSS which handles this:

```css
#Controls > ul > li.topTip:hover:after {
    top: -100px;
}
```

Which you can then toggle with jQuery:

```
$("#Controls > ul > li").addClass("topTip");
```

Comment: Great!! Its an awesome ans. and explanation. Thank you for sharing. You deserve for 30.6k.